# Vue - Axios is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

In a **Laravel+Vue** project i trying to use axios to get a API response. **Axios** call a Laravel endpoint and get controller response.

The code looks

JS

```
require("./bootstrap");

import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";

import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import es from "vuetify/es5/locale/es";
import en from "vuetify/es5/locale/en";
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";

import ContadoresComponent from "./components/ContadorComponent.vue";
import GatewaysComponent from "./components/GatewayComponent.vue";
import MainComponent from "./components/MainComponent.vue";


const routes = [{
        path: "/",
        name: "principal",
        component: MainComponent
    },
    {
        path: "/contadores",
        name: "contadores",
        component: ContadoresComponent
    },
    {
        path: "/gateways",
        name: "gateways",
        component: GatewaysComponent
    }
];

window.Vue = require("vue");
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueI18n);
Vue.use(axios);

Vue.component(
    "drawer-component",
    require("./components/DrawerComponent.vue").default
    /*  methods: {
          changeLocale (lang) {
            this.$vuetify.lang.current = lang
          },
    },*/
);

Vue.component(
    "table-component",
    require("./components/TableComponent.vue").default
);

export default new Vuetify({
    icons: {
        iconfont: "mdi"
    },
    lang: {
        locales: {
            es,
            en
        },
        current: "es"
    }
});

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

new Vue({
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    router
}).$mount("#app");
```

Vue (Vuetify)

```
<template>
  <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-card class="mx-auto">
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title class="headline">Contador</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <table-component></table-component>
      </v-card>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
axios.get("/contadores").then(response => console.log(response));
</script>
```

The error: Return axios is not defined, but i think that i defined in App.js file.

Anybody see the error?

Comment: in the `<script>` section of your Vue component, add `import axios from 'axios';` at the top.

Comment: Console return Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You still need to import it in the second file. You scrip tag should look like this:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
axios.get("/contadores").then(response => console.log(response));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported axios in your file.

To solve this issue either import it in your file where you want to use it as below

`import axios from 'axios';`

**OR**

If you don't want to import it in each component where you use it, you can add it to the Vue prototype:

```
window.axios = require('axios');

//... configure axios...

Vue.prototype.$http = window.axios;
```

Then in any component you can use

```
this.$http.post('event/store', {
    'name': this.name,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach that I use in my projects, is to use the library [vue-axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios), which is very simple to be installed. In case you need to install the dependencies in your project through the commands `npm install --save axios vue-axios` and then import it into the `main.js` file or the main file of your application:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
 
Vue.use (VueAxios, axios)
```

The use of axios in the component will be through `` this.axios.get(`${url}`) ``. Another approach already exposed by friends here at StackOverflow is to import the axios directly into the component you want to use:

```
<template>
<div>
...
</div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
   name: 'ComponentName',
   methods: {
      async getAsyncApi() {
         try {
            const result = await axios.get(`${url}`);
        } catch(e) {
            window.console.error('Error! ', e.message);
        }
      },
      getApi() {
         let result;
         axios.get(`${url}`).then((r) => {
           result = r;
         }).catch(e => window.console.error('Error! ', e.message));
      },
   },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the error with

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("ENDPOINT")
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }
};
```